# Value of type 'UICollectionViewCell' has no member 'imageView'

Tags: iphone, swift3, xcode8, ios10

I'm setting up a new project with a `UICollectionView` that displays an image. I created the `ViewController` and the `CellViewController`, just like its supposed to.

In the `CellViewController` the code is the following:

```
import UIKit

class ClubCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
}
```

But in the `ViewController` when I'm setting up the image it gives me the error. Here's the code:

```
 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier,
                                                      for: indexPath)
    // Configure the cell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "pic1")
    return cell;
}
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Did you connect your `@IBOutlet` to your `.xib` file?

Comment: The error i am getting is Value of type 'UICollectionViewCell' has no member 'imageView' Although I have connected the cell to the new class ClubCollectionViewCell at my storyboard !

Answer (score 2):

You should cast your collectionViewCell subclass as your custom one `ClubCollectionViewCell`.

Use `guard` to check for the type of the cell, do `fatalError()` if it fails.

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier,
                                                            for: indexPath) as? ClubCollectionViewCell else {
                                                                    fatalError("Wrong cell class dequeued")
    }
        // Configure the cell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "pic1")
        return cell
 }
```

Comment: Thanks s lot for your answer, but I tried to do that and the app crashes !

Comment: did you set the register the `reuseIdentifier` of the cell in storyboard or in code?

Comment: I set the identifier in storyboard as Cell then in code i wrote private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

Comment: what is the crash you are experiencing, when you try to check the type? Could you post the crash log?